# Enable public access for rabbitmq server running on Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, azure-virtual-machine

I've rabbitmq installed on Azure VM and it's working fine with the deployed app on the VM. But I want to do some testing and that's why I've allowed port 5672 to be access publicly on the VM. But I also need to allow public access to the rabbitmq node through rabbitmq.conf file.

I didn't have rabbitmq.conf file in %Appdata%/Rabbitmq folder when I installed rabbitmq. But I've created one using the example file (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example).

Now how can I enable public access in this file? I tried using following snippet but rabbitmq service failed to start afterwards with the error file in the %Appdata%/RabbitMq folder. So I suspect there's is syntax difference in rabbitmq.config file and rabbitnq.conf file.

```
[
    {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ip_range, [
        {tag_masks,
            [{'ip-private', [<<"::FFFF:192.168.0.0/112">>]}]},
        {default_masks, [<<"::0/0">>]}
    ]}
].
```